# Python. Programa adivinar numero aleatorio (rango 1,2) sin break ni continue

Tags: python-3.x, while

Tengo que hacer un programa que genere un numero aleatorio, nos han dicho con el rango mas bajo, entiendo que (1,2) y que pida intentos hasta que lo aciertes.Introduzco la combinatoria reducida que da el (1,2) y no hay manera, no sale del bucle. ¿Alguien podría explicarme porque no sale del bucle tal y como tengo el código? Por cierto en principio no podemos usar ni break ni continue. Muchas gracias. El código lo tengo así:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,2)
intento = input ("adivina el numero")
while intento != num:
    intento = input ("Acceso denegado.Introduce la contraseña")
print("Acceso permitido")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La opcion comentada tambien es valida. Es muy importante pasar por int el random.randrange y poner los dos valores, inicio y fin de rango. Entiendo.

```
import random
clave=int(random.randrange(1,10))
#lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#clave = random.choice(lista)
intento = int(input("adivina el numero"))
while intento != clave:
    intento = int(input("Acceso denegado.Introduce la contraseña"))
print("Acceso permitido")
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema lo habías solucionado en tu anterior pregunta pero se te ha pasado por alto y es una trampa para novatos.

La función `input()` devuelve una cadena de caracteres, pero `randint()` devuelve enteros, asi que 'intento' y 'num' son dos tipos diferentes de variable, por lo que la condición del while siempre es True. Es como si num valiese 2 y tu lo estuvieras comparando con 'dos' o 'felipe' o 'mazorca', siempre va a ser diferente

Anida la función `int(input(..))` y ya está.

Comment: OUCH,... tenes razon.. mala mia.. me quede con el texto, y no vi que era un input... igual, es un input que dice cualquier cosa.. pero cuando tenes razon, tenes razon...

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos, de verdad que me estáis ayudando mucho mas de lo que aprendo en clase.